Seeking Midrash that says that Moshe cannot enter the land because he killed the Mitzri
On 'rav lach' Hashem tells Moshe he cannot enter the land because he killed the Mitzri. Moshe responds that Hashem killed many Mitzrim. Hashem responds asking Moshe if he knows the ways of God (or something like that)
This is from book Accepting the Yoke of Heaven by Yeshayahu Leibowitz who happens to be the brother of Nechama Leibowitz.

I've never heard that one before, and it seems rather surprising given the simple reading of the verses. It would, however, be consistent with Yeshayau Leibowitz's worldview. He was strongly opposed to Jews getting drunk on power, and would switch from a walled city to an unwalled city to avoid keeping Purim altogether, as he didn't want to celebrate Jews killing their enemies if he could halachically avoid it.

My brother found 2 sources from a Sefaria search so I'm posting here
Otzar Midrashim, Midrashim on Moses Our Master, The Death of Moses (Version 1) 4
לא אמות כי אחיה וגו׳, א״ל הקב״ה רב לך עד פה תבוא ולא תוסיף, קרא את יהושע ואצונו, אמר לפניו רבש״ע מפני מה אני מת? אם בשביל כבודו של יהושע יכנס יהושע לשררה ואני אצא....א״ל מרע״ה כתיב כל אלה יפעל אל וכו׳ ואתה מתנהג עם בריותך במדת רחמים פעם אחת ושתים ושלש, ואני עון אחד יש לי ואין אתה מכפר לי, א״ל הקב״ה משה שש עונות בידך ולא גליתי לך שום אחד מהם: בתחלה אמרת לי שלח נא ביד...א״ל האתה גדול מיצחק? א״ל יצא מחלציו מי שיחריב את ביתך ובניו יהרגו את בניך כהניך ולויך, א״ל הקב״ה כלום אמרתי לך שתהרוג את המצרי? א״ל ואתה הרגת כל בכורי מצרים ואני אמות בשביל מצרי אחד?!...חזר משה והודה על הכל ואמר לפניו רבש״ע גדלתני והרבה טובות עשית לי שאיני יכול לספר אחת מני אלף, וכל העולם יודעים מה שגדלתני וכבדתני, ג״כ כל העולם יודעים שאתה ה׳ אחד יחיד בעולמך ואין זולתך ואין דומה לך, אתה...בראת עליונים ותחתונים, אתה הוא ראשון ואתה הוא אחרון, ומי יוכל למלל גבורותיך, אלא דבר אחד אני מבקש ממך: שאעבור את הירדן.
Otzar Midrashim, New York, 1915
A New Israeli Commentary on Pirkei Avot 5:18:7
משה, כזכור, פותח את מסכת אבות והוא שב ונזכר פעמיים בפרק החותם אותה , וכך מקנה הופעתו מסגרת למסכת כולה, ורק דברי שבח נאמרים בה אודותיו. והנה, לפי האמור כאן זיכה משה את הרבים ועל כן גם לא חטא ....על פי אחד מן החיבורים המאוחרים שבספרות זו, "מדרש פטירת משה רבנו עליו השלום", מוחה משה בפני האלוהים על שנגזר עליו למות, ובמיוחד עוד קודם לכניסתו לארץ ישראל; לדבריו אין בידו שום עוון שבגינו הוא חייב למות...אך לא פחות מהם, לפי חיבור זה, נגזר על משה למות בשל הריגת המצרי : "אמר לו הקב"ה: כלום אמרתי לך שתהרוג את המצרי? אמר לו [משה]: ואתה הרגת כל בכורי מצרים, ואני אמות בשביל מצרי אחד?...אמר לו הקב"ה: ואתה דומה אלי, ממית ומחיה? כלום אתה יכול להחיות כמוני?!". מסתבר שלדעת חיבור זה לא צריך היה משה להרוג את המצרי, ויכול היה למנוע אותו מהכאת העברי בדרכים אחרות.
Pirke Avot, a New Israeli Commentary, by Avigdor Shinan; Jerusalem, 2009
Texts

Welcome to the site. The second source simply paraphrases the first one (Shinan states explicitly that he's referring to Midrash of Moshe's Death).

Welcome to MiYodeya and thanks for this first question and answer. Since MY is different from other sites you might be used to, see here for a guide which might help understand the site. Great to have you learn with us!
